# Shiny: Multiple conditionalPanels, same Conditions

Tags: r, shiny

I am having issues using textOutput in a ui that contains multiple conditionalPanels that use the same conditions.  In the example below, textOutput("sampleReturn2") is not working properly (i.e., not registering the 'school' input).  Is there anything I can do to re-structure so that these work correctly?

PS I am new to stack overflow as of today - I hope the example below provides enough info.  Thanks in advance!

```
sampleFunction      <-      function(report, school)
{
paste(report, school, "TEST", sep = '')
}

aa <- shinyUI(
fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(1),
        column(2, h4(strong('Sample Tool')), br(),
            selectInput("report",
            label = 'Input 1',
            choices = c(
                ' ',
                'AA' = '1',
                'BB' = '2'),
            selected = ' ',
            multiple = FALSE
            )),
        column(4, br(), br(), br(),
            conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.report == 1",
            selectInput("school", width = '100%',
                label = 'Input 2a',
                choices = c(' ' , '11', '22', '33', '44'),
                selected = ' ',
                multiple = FALSE
            )),
            conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.report == 2",
            selectInput("school", width = '100%',
                label = 'Input 2b',
                choices = c(' ', '55', '66', '77', '88'),
                selected = ' ',
                multiple = FALSE
            )))
    ), 
    hr(),
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.report == 1",
    fluidRow(
        column(6,
            fluidRow(
                column(6, h4(strong('Actual SPR Scores'), align = 'left'))
                ),
            "Sample Return 1", textOutput("sampleReturn1")
            ),
        column(6,
            fluidRow(
                column(6, h4(strong('Adjusted SPR Scores'), align = 'left'))
                ),
            "ADJUSTED AA REPORT SCORES"
            )),
        hr(),
        tabsetPanel(type = 'tabs',
            tabPanel("CATEGORY A", 
                column(6, "CATEGORY A ACTUAL SCORES"),
                column(6, "CATEGORY A ADJUSTED SCORES")
                ),
            tabPanel("CATEGORY B", 
                column(6, "CATEGORY B ACTUAL SCORES"),
                column(6, "CATEGORY B ADJUSTED SCORES")
                ),
            tabPanel("CATEGORY C",
                column(6, "CATEGORY C ACTUAL SCORES"),
                column(6, "CATEGORY C ADJUSTED SCORES")
                ),
            tabPanel("CATEGORY D", 
                column(6, "CATEGORY D ACTUAL SCORES"),
                column(6, "CATEGORY D ADJUSTED SCORES")
                )
            )
        ),
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.report == 2",
    fluidRow(
        column(6,
            fluidRow(
                column(6, h4(strong('Actual SPR Scores'), align = 'left'))
                ),
            "Sample Return 2", textOutput("sampleReturn2")
            ),
        column(6,
            fluidRow(
                column(6, h4(strong('Adjusted SPR Scores'), align = 'left'))
                ),
            "ADJUSTED BB REPORT SCORES"
            )),
        hr(),
        tabsetPanel(type = 'tabs',
            tabPanel("CATEGORY A", 
                column(6, "CATEGORY A ACTUAL SCORES"),
                column(6, "CATEGORY A ADJUSTED SCORES")
                ),
            tabPanel("CATEGORY B", 
                column(6, "CATEGORY B ACTUAL SCORES"),
                column(6, "CATEGORY B ADJUSTED SCORES")
                ),
            tabPanel("CATEGORY C",
                column(6, "CATEGORY C ACTUAL SCORES"),
                column(6, "CATEGORY C ADJUSTED SCORES")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

bb <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
output$sampleReturn1        <-      renderText({sampleFunction(input$report, input$school)})
output$sampleReturn2        <-      renderText({sampleFunction(input$report, input$school)})        
})

runApp(list(ui = aa, server = bb))
```

Comment: It's not very clear what your intent is. Perhaps you could describe the goal better in words. And saying "not working properly" isn't very specific. Are you getting an error? Are you not getting the behavior you expect -- if so, what exactly is the behavior you expect? I'm not exactly sure what "not registering the school input" means. What exactly should we be looking for in the output? Perhaps simplify the example to make it clearer (but good job including a reproducible example).

Comment: Your suggestions are helpful, thanks.  My goal is to use the same function (in this case, sampleFunction()), to place reactive output in different locations in my ui depending on  what is chosen in a set of two initial inputs (in this example, 'report' and 'school').  I have given the outputs different ids even though the function they use is the same.  I am getting blank output for the second output instead of what I would expect, and changing the inputs doesn't change the output like I would expect.  The first output works perfectly.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I think the problem is in the school input. Because you create two "school"-inputs. So you have to use different name for the other "school"-input like school2. That might break something else.

Comment: Mikael, that was most certainly the problem!  Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes - thanks :).